# "Who said we'll have a new champion?" - is this a correct sentence?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

The quoted person thinks that the reigning champion will defend her title, and expresses his opinion as if he is arguing with those who has doubts. Is the sentence is question grammatically correct? Or is "Who said we'd have a new champion?" more accurate? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic. See the [help/on-topic] for more details.

Answer (score -2):

Both are fine. They are using different tenses but have exactly the same effect.